# Windows 8 Notification Service notification from command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-8, notifications

Can you send a windows 8 Windows Notification Service (WNS) via command prompt?

Example: notification when sass stylesheet compiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send Windows 8 Notifications from any desktop application.

It should be the same as [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2#content) example except starting with a command prompt project.

See the msdn quickstart [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh802768).

Comment: I didn't know if there was just a command or way to add that command so it could be added to a batch file.

Comment: If you read the example, it appears to be significantly more complicated than that.

Comment: I found under that in order to display toasts, a desktop application must have a shortcut on the Start menu. I guess at this point this is just not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

What you want (well, what I wanted, so I expect you do, too) is [toaster](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster).

> A wee Win8 console notifications app. Post toast notifications from the console, making it easy to integrate into existing batch scripts etc.

Just download the master.zip file, there's a compiled binary called toast.exe.

From command prompt or batch file:

```
toast -t "Title text" -m "Message text goes here" -p c:\users\me\picture.png
```

Comment: Just for information for those, like me, looking for a solution W10, this crashes on most command examples...

Answer (score 3):

There is a command-line utility called [snoretoast](https://github.com/KDE/snoretoast).

It has the [binaries](https://github.com/KDE/snoretoast#releases-and-binaries) that you can put somewhere. (One option is to extract the provided "SnoreToast.exe" into the "c:\Windows\System32" folder. That folder is already on your `PATH` and so the command will be immediately available from everywhere on your system).

Once the binaries are installed, all you have to do is invoke the command. For example,

```
SnoreToastGui -t "Way back" -m "Back to the future"
```

displays a toast notification where the title is "Way back" and message is "Back to the future".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [java-wns](http://fernandospr.github.io/java-wns/) library to create a custom command line application to suite your needs.